# Empty editText causing app to crash when trying to calculate

Tags: java, android

I have an app with 4 EditText and one button that is supposed to calculate the inputs given

When one of those are left empty then the app crashes

How can I validate to throw an error when a EditText is left empty

Comment: post the crash log.

Comment: You're probably getting a **NumberFormatException**. Because you probably think that an **empty string** would be parsed as a **0**. Which is **totally wrong**

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TextUtils.isEmpty(stringData)` and it is preferred. For `string.isEmpty()`, a null string value will throw a `NullPointerException`.

`TextUtils` will always return a `boolean` value. In code, the former simply calls the equivalent of the other, plus a null check.

```
EditText myEditText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText myEditText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText myEditText3 = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
EditText myEditText4 = findViewById(R.id.editText4);

String myData1 = myEditText1.getText().toString();
String myData2 = myEditText2.getText().toString();
String myData3 = myEditText3.getText().toString();
String myData4 = myEditText4.getText().toString();

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(myData1) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(myData2) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(myData3) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(myData4)) {
    //use edit text data
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Fields value can not be empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: And if it's a int?

Comment: Then also TextUtils.isEmpty() is working fine. Because, when you entered a data into an edittext like String type, int tpye or whatever it is, all the data are formatted as a string. 

You can parse this data to int for further purpose.

String myData1 = myEditText1.getText().toString();
int myInt = Integer.parseInt(myData1);

Comment: it says TextUtils cannot be applied to int

Comment: Can you share your code with https://pastebin.com?

Then I can see what happens there.

Comment: Hopefully, it is working now. Try and let me know, it is working or not?

TextUtils will only deal with string.

https://pastebin.com/1qwyqcAP

Comment: thanks for all your help. i am going to try it out now.

Comment: damn my app still crashed

Comment: What says in you logcat error?

and sorry for my mistake, the line will be 

TextUtils.isEmpty(assignmentOneInput.getText().toString()

for showing your error code no need to add ! sign before TextUtils

Comment: 02-17 19:37:20.526 12555-12555/com.example.mycalc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mycalc, PID: 12555
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
        at com.example.mycalc.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)

Comment: part of the logcat

Comment: everything else in the app works besides the empty editText validation. the error message displays if number greater than 100. but the app still crashes if field is left empty.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the button check if the EditText is empty or not

Try below code

```
if(editText.getText().toString.length() == 0){
        // Display toast 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter something !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Or you can use a library called [AwesomeValiation](https://github.com/thyrlian/AwesomeValidation)

Comment: If you want to check for string length then logical condition should be rather `==0`

Comment: I’ve been searching google and YouTube like crazy trying to figure out a fix and everything that I’ve been trying ain’t working. But these codes look different so Thanks guys will try it out later then give feedback

Answer (score 0):

First you need to link the edit text and button with the id

```
EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText editText3 = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
EditText editText4 = findViewById(R.id.editText4);
```

Now you can get the value from the editText by using the below code

```
 String data = editText.getText();
```

For check the null value

```
if (data.isEmpty ){

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"the data is "+data,Toast.SHORT_LENGTH).show;

}
```